# Use spech_recognition to write down system audio

Tags: python, speech-recognition, live-streaming, pyaudio, google-speech-api

I am trying to use Python `speech_recognition` to get an input from the **system audio** and then to print it as output. Unfortunately, I'm having some problems with the devices list. In fact, it seems that speech_recognition only recognizes microphones as devices of input.

My idea is the following: I am very slow at writing down notes of important videocalls, so I would like to have Python speech_recognition write them down for me so I can catch up with missing pieces. Do you think it is possible? How?

This is my code until now:

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

r=sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold=4000

for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))

# returns a list of 15 devices (microphone, system speakers, headphones...)

with sr.Microphone(device_index=4) as source:
   audio = r.listen(source)
# index = 4 is my headphones 

try:
   print("Speech was:" + r.recognize_google(audio))
except LookupError:
   print('Speech not understood')
```

When just looking at it, it seems good. But when running it, it cannot recognize my headphones (system audio) as devices and returns the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 10, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=4) as source:
  File "...\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 141, in __enter__
    input=True,  # stream is an input stream
  File "...pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "...pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels
```

and when putting "normal microphone" as input:

```
line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

Can you help me figure this out please?

Answer (score 0):

The microphone error is given when the result of the audio wasn't understood as words. You can fix that by adding a try/except around the statement with "except [the name of the import].UnknownValueError. This will result in whatever is put under except to be run if the "UnknownValueError" error is encountered. As for the headphones, I believe the issue is that you are using an output device for an input function.